# orderBy not working properly on ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

everything is working fine, but with an anomaly of 1 month.
I want to show months in descending order,

```
ng-options="i as  payrollRule.prd_date_display for (i,payrollRule) in payrollRules |  orderBy:'-time'"
```

with JSON http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=5180c8005b1072418925a0f01968bdff[enter link description here](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=5180c8005b1072418925a0f01968bdff)

but as you see in img, only 01 Apr 2014 is coming at 2nd position instead of last. Any suggestion?

[image: Bug Image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2HYj.png

Comment: Are you using an object for your options list by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should use your HTML syntax:

```
<select ng-model="selected" ng-options="i as  i.prd_date_display for i in payrollRules |  orderBy:'-time'"></select>
```

The i is the object that will be in your selected variable, your `i` variable is what you want to iterate over, hence the `for i in payrollRules`. And then you display the property you want with `as  i.prd_date_display`.

However, this still result in an extra empty option since you have that empty object. You might want to filter it out.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aBccw/568/)

Comment: O God, I hail to you :) Kudos Bro.